# Flushing RxJava buffer on application close

Tags: android, rx-java, timber-android

Using Timber, I wrote a `FileTree` logger that will write Android logs to files on the disk. I buffer the logs, flushing to disk every 2 minutes, or 100 log messages, whichever comes first. The buffer prevents each log message from triggering a IO write, so as to not overload the IO resources by immediately writing every single log message.

I'm using `RxJava` to handle this task. A short snippet (taken from [here](https://medium.com/@karnsaheb/logging-to-disk-reactively-on-android-68c4d0ec489)):

```java
logBuffer.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnEach((log) -> {
        processed++;

        if(processed % 100 == 0) {
            flush();
        }
    })
    .buffer(flush.mergeWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe((logs) -> {
        // Flush the logs to the file
        try {
            File logFile = new File(logDir, "app.log");

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(logFile, true);

            for(LogMessage msg : logs) {
                fw.append(msg.toString());
            }

            fw.flush();

            flushCompleted.onNext(logFile.length());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Failed to flush logs");
        }
    });
```

I use the "flush" subject if I need to trigger a flush manually.
I plant the `FileTree` in Timber within the `Application`'s `onCreate()`:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree(), new FileTree(getApplicationContext()));
    }
}
```

This is also where the subscriptions for `RxJava` are setup. I have two questions about this:

- If the application closes for some reason, presumably the log flush won't get triggered by a timer or by receiving enough log messages. Should I simply place a manual call to flush in *every* `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` function? Is there a better way to do this?
- Secondly, `RxJava` complains that I ignore the result of ".subscribe()", presumably because I won't ever call `dispose()` on it. I'm not sure exactly how to handle this case. The subscriptions have the same lifecycle as the Application itself, so I'm not sure that removing it within a particular `Activity`'s `onDestroy` would make sense. Further, my app has several entry points (the main activity, a background service, and a few others) that all make use of the logging facilities, so when to unsubscribe/dispose the `RxJava` subscriptions isn't clear. My intuition is that I don't need to dispose them because they will be cleared whenever the Application is removed by the operating system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instad of copying that code on each activity finish, you could use a `BaseActivity`, or use `Application's` activity state callbacks API ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) ).

I should note that for the purposes of chosing a lifecycle method to flush, no method after `onPause()` is guaranteed to be called by the OS. If the operating system needs to kill your app for low-memory, it's not guaranteed that `onDestroy()` will be called ( rather it will just kill your process ).

To quote https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity :

> Note the "Killable" column in the above table -- for those methods
> that are marked as being killable, after that method returns the
> process hosting the activity may be killed by the system at any time
> without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you
> should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as
> user edits) to storage

---

---

2. If the 'lifecycle' of your code is the same as the application's, its perfectly OK to ignore the subscription result ( as you won't ever dispose of the subscription ).  Just make sure that you aren't catching in that scope parts that need to have a shorter lifecycle ( for example don't keep a reference to an activity context there, or you'll be leaking it )